# Question in tangled state with broken link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

The question [Transfer a folder from local system … to … virtual system](https://superuser.com/q/602042/150988) was, according to [its revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/602042/revisions), migrated from StackOverflow to SuperUser
over a year ago (May 31 ’13 at 9:14), and then closed 2014-07-19. 
The question page says,

### migration rejected from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16850504/revisions)

[image: "migration rejected" snapshot]

and the link (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16850504/revisions)
goes to StackOverflow’s charming 404 page.

It seems unlikely that any trace of the question remained on StackOverflow
over a year after it was migrated to SuperUser,
so I suspect that the link was broken when it was posted, on July 19. 
This seems like bad behavior.  (And is it really appropriate to say “migration rejected”
over 400 days after the question was initially migrated?)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the 404 not found by clicking on the hyperlink with the display text of "stackoverflow.com" in the migration rejected message.

Answer (score 1):

The community user regularly goes around cleaning up [(i.e. deleting)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/159016) old questions.   In this case:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

The question itself was not particularly answerable as it was simply to broadly scoped, there are any number of methods to transfer files and the original asker gave no details of what they tried. It showed no effort to find a solution and could have been closed as a duplicate of any number of questions. It got closed and as it had originally been migrated that migration was rejected.

The original question was not a good fit for Stack Overflow at all and so the migration was (partly) correct except for the fact that the [golden rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446) was disobeyed. If it were worthwhile it could almost certainly be undeleted on Stack overflow, but it shouldn't be because it was off topic.

The link you saw would work and you would see a valid (but deleted) question if you had more than 10K rep on Stack Overflow. As it stands though without that reputation all you see is a 404 page.

Comment: No, I’m not arguing that it’s a good question. I’m arguing that we shouldn’t say, “This question … may be eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.” and then provide a link to the site where the question originated that ***doesn’t*** point to a copy of the question. If it’s been deleted, say so.

Comment: In that case I have cleared the migration history on the question and re-closed it. The answer it has might help users in the future, but other than that the question itself is not likely to get any attention. The original question would have been deleted, but would still be able to be undeleted if it warranted it.

Comment: I can still see the revision history of migration stubs even after they've been deleted, even if I don't have enough rep, but when I try to go to the question itself, I get a 404 error.